# retina.js doesn't work for absolute img src path

Tags: javascript

The logo image is not being swapped to retina version by retina.js if I use absolute image src path. Though the @2x version exists but it cant be loaded. When I remove absolute path i.e. my website domain name from img src, and use only relative path such as "images/logo.png" then the retina version loads with no issue at all. What's happening out there?

Comment: not a big and special code; just `<img src....`

Comment: open developer tool and inspect network requests, is there any image request?

Comment: Saw the same bug today. Does not work for absolute img src path indeed